# jQuery is loading classes correctly, but not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I know this is probably terrible code but I'm on a time crunch. I want to have jQuery change some classes around when the page reaches a breakpoint. It works when the window resizes, but doesn't work if the page is loaded at smaller sizes. The HTML shows that it has loaded the correct classes, but it displays incorrectly in the browser window.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        resizeWindow();
    });

    $( window ).resize(function() {
        resizeWindow();
    });

    var isBreakPoint = function (bp) {
    var bps = [320, 875, 1115, 2048],
        w = $(window).width(),
        min, max
    for (var i = 0, l = bps.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (bps[i] === bp) {
        min = bps[i-1] || 0
        max = bps[i]
        break
      }
    }
    return w > min && w <= max
}
    function resizeWindow() {
        if(isBreakPoint(2048)) {
            $( "#hero" ).addClass( "col6" ).removeClass("col2");
            $( "#sectionStory" ).addClass( "col5" ).removeClass("col4");
            $( "#headerConeZone" ).addClass( "-c7" ).removeClass("-c6").load(location.href + " #headerConeZone");
            $( "#headerConeZone1" ).addClass( "x1 y1" ).removeClass("");
            $( "#headerConeZone2" ).addClass( "x1 y2" ).removeClass("");

            $( "#pConeZone" ).addClass( "c5 -c7 y2" ).removeClass("c1 y3");
            $( "#sectionEpic" ).addClass( "col6" ).removeClass("col2");
            $( "#imageEpic" ).addClass( "c4 -c8 r2 -r4" ).removeClass("x2 y1");
            $( "#pEpic" ).addClass( "x2" ).removeClass("c2 -c4");
            $( "#pWolf1" ).addClass( "-c5" ).removeClass("-c8");
            $( "#pWolf2" ).addClass( "-c5" ).removeClass("-c8");
        } else if(isBreakPoint(1115)) {
            $( "#hero" ).addClass( "col2" ).removeClass("col6");
            $( "#sectionStory" ).addClass( "col4" ).removeClass("col5");
            $( "#headerConeZone1" ).addClass( "" ).removeClass("x1 y1");
            $( "#headerConeZone2" ).addClass( "" ).removeClass("x1 y2");

            $( "#pConeZone" ).addClass( "y3" ).removeClass("c5 -c7 y2");
            $( "#sectionEpic" ).addClass( "col6" ).removeClass("col2");
            $( "#imageEpic" ).addClass( "c4 -c8 r2 -r4" ).removeClass("x2 y1");
            $( "#pEpic" ).addClass( "x2" ).removeClass("c2 -c4");
            $( "#pWolf1" ).addClass( "-c5" ).removeClass("-c8");
            $( "#pWolf2" ).addClass( "-c5" ).removeClass("-c8");
        } else if(isBreakPoint(875)) {
            $( "#headerConeZone" ).addClass( "-c6" ).removeClass("-c7");
            $( "#headerConeZone1" ).addClass( "" ).removeClass("x1 y1");
            $( "#headerConeZone2" ).addClass( "" ).removeClass("x1");
            $( "#pConeZone" ).addClass( "y3" ).removeClass("c5 -c7 y2");
            $( "#sectionEpic" ).addClass( "col2" ).removeClass("col6");
            $( "#imageEpic" ).addClass( "x2 y1" ).removeClass("c4 -c8 r2 -r4");
            $( "#pEpic" ).addClass( "c2 -c4" ).removeClass("x2");
            $( "#pWolf1" ).addClass( "-c8" ).removeClass("-c5");
            $( "#pWolf2" ).addClass( "-c8" ).removeClass("-c5");
        } else {}
    }
```